# C# Odbc Query Result Incorrect

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I am struggling here trying to understand (after a lot of research a futzing with this) why my MySQL query in C# is returning only one row and the values are wrong.

```
public static void loadCombinedPaymentExportData(Int32 iFromId = 0)
{
    // VERIFIED STATE OF CONNECTION (OUTPUTS "OPEN")
    Console.Write(oConn.State+"\n");

    // TRIED USING PREPARED STATEMENTS FIRST
    //OdbcCommand oCommand = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM v_payment_export_combined_rec WHERE id > ? LIMIT 10", oConn);
    //oCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OdbcType.Int).Value = iFromId;

    // ENDED UP TRYING A MORE DIRECT APPROACH SO I COULD SEE WHAT IS HAPPENING
    string sQuery = "SELECT * FROM v_payment_export_combined_rec WHERE id > " + iFromId.ToString() + " LIMIT 10";

    // OUTPUTS "SELECT * FROM v_payment_export_combined_rec WHERE id > 0 LIMIT 10"
    Console.WriteLine(sQuery);

    OdbcCommand oCommand = new OdbcCommand(sQuery, oConn);
    using (OdbcDataReader oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // THIS ENTERS INTO THE BLOCK AS HAVING ROWS
        if (oReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (oReader.Read())
            {
                // THIS ONLY OUTPUTS ONCE AS "Data: 1"
                Console.WriteLine("\nData: {0}", oReader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.\n");
        }

        oReader.Close();
        oCommand.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The issue here is if I run the same exact query on the database using my SQL editor, I have something like 190k+ rows come back from the view, and the lowest `id` is 8. In fact, I tried adding additional output like:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nData: {0} | {1} | {2}", oReader.GetString(0), oReader.GetString(1), oReader.GetString(2));
```

And every single one of them comes back as a **1**, which is incorrect as the 2nd column has real text.

[image]

Curiously, I had previously done a similar test on another table using this same logic and it worked just fine.

What am I messing up?

**[EDIT]**

Just tried using the MySQL .NET Connector instead of ODBC and got the same result.

```
string sQuery = "SELECT * FROM v_payment_export_combined_rec WHERE id > " + iFromId.ToString() + " LIMIT 10;";

MySqlCommand oCommand = new MySqlCommand(sQuery, oConn);
using (MySqlDataReader oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (oReader.HasRows)
    {
        while (oReader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nData: {0}", oReader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.\n");
    }

    oReader.Close();
    oCommand.Dispose();
}
```

I will keep investigating here to see if I can figure out what is going on.

Comment: This seems to be correct. Are you sure that the database is the same one?

Comment: @Steve Yes. I was able to pull users from the same database using the same logic. I just downloaded the .NET connector for MySQL and am giving that a try instead of ODBC. Maybe that will be the trick...

Comment: This code uses a technique that is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks. While this query only deals with an integer parameter, and so is probably safe, others queries in the app that use the same technique are likely crazy-vulnerable. Using string substitution for adding data to sql is practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, I am aware of that. Hence the commented out prepared statements I used first.

Comment: @cillosis If you could use the NET connector then use it and discard ODBC

Comment: @Steve So, just implemented it using the .NET connector for MySQL and am getting the same result -- only one "row" and any index I try to grab with the Reader returns a "1" instead of data.

Comment: In this query, the "table" is actually a MySQL view. I just changed the query to try to pull from my users table (leaving all the other logic intact) and it worked fine. So maybe there isn't a way to query a view with ODBC or the MySQL/.NET connector?

Comment: Probably is not related, but if ID is an integer,why use GetString on it? Try to use oReader[0].ToString() instead. However querying a the view or a table should be the same unless something very subtle happens on your view.

Comment: @Steve I've tried `oReader.GetInt32(0)` also. I've narrowed it down to basically this not wanting to read from a MySQL view. A table works fine. So, I'm wondering if this is a limitation of the Reader since it tries to read row by row and a view is essentially a temp table. Is there another way to get data other than a Reader in C#?

Comment: Reader is the fastest way. You could use an MySqlDataAdapter and call Fill (see the docs and example of [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx), the MySql works in the same way)

Comment: However if the only value returned is 1 not 8, it seems that it is completely off

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I will explore that option.

Comment: I would also try to find a specific record like ID=8